# Jupyter dosen't return the MapBox map

Tags: jupyter-notebook, mapbox, jupyter, mapbox-gl

I am trying to test [the jupyter version](https://github.com/mapbox/mapboxgl-jupyter) of **mapbox gl js**.

i copied [the code of this example](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mapbox/mapboxgl-jupyter/blob/master/examples/notebooks/point-viz-types-example.ipynb) in my jupyter notebook , and attempted to return the map,

the result is an empty map !!:

[image]

what is wrong ?
please let me know if the map is returned in your devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem,the problem was with the token :

so  instead of:

`token=os.getenv(my_public_token)`

(this function reads a system environment variable so i need ti set a **MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN environment variable** if i want to use it)

the solution is directly :
    `token=my_public_token`

Note: ***my_public_token*** is the public token of your mapbox account